# HTML, CSS, JS not running

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to html, css, and js and have been following along with codecademy. I just created my files for the first time and am trying to follow this https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/9ewogtwL/ example to try and get a video with an overlay of play/pause. I can't get the video to play with the codes below, not sure what I'm doing wrong or missing. This is exactly how my codes are written in each file. My guess is that either my html or js is not written properly?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <video class="video">
            <source src="http://e14aaeb709f7cde1ae68-a1d0a134a31b545b257b15f8a8ba5726.r70.cf3.rackcdn.com/projects/31432/1427815464209-bf74131a7528d0ea5ce8c0710f530bb5/1280x720.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <div class="playpause"></div> 
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

scripts.js

```
$('.video').parent().click(function () {
if($(this).children(".video").get(0).paused){
    $(this).children(".video").get(0).play();
    $(this).children(".playpause").fadeOut();
}else{
   $(this).children(".video").get(0).pause();
    $(this).children(".playpause").fadeIn();
}
});
```

mystyle.css

```
.video {
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid black;
}
.wrapper{
display:table;
width:auto;
position:relative;
width:50%;
}
.playpause {
background-image:url(http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/2315/default_icon/256/media_play_pause_resume.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:50%;
height:50%;
position:absolute;
left:0%;
right:0%;
top:0%;
bottom:0%;
margin:auto;
background-size:contain;
background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you press `F12` on your browser and check the console for errors?

Comment: where do you include jQuery library?

Comment: @VladimirM I haven't included the jQuery library... I didn't see it included in the example I was following, didn't know I had to put that in too. Where would it go?

Comment: check the following link for how to include it: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: You don't see **JavaScript + jQuery 2.1.3** in the corner of the Javascript section of the fiddle?

Comment: @Barmar Oh, I didn't realize that's what it meant. Sorry, no idea what I'm doing

Comment: @VladimirM Cool, thank you!

Comment: @Pam You should probably try reading tutorials rather than just copying examples that have no explanations.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script.js contains JQuery code and not vanilla JS. 
You need to link to the JQuery library which is required for the code to function.

Try adding a CDN source to your head tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

See below link for reference.

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp